# Istio Installation Failure

Tags: istio, servicemesh

error installing Istio in Mac M1.

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
```

> Error: Get “http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s”: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use other installation method - "[Istio Operator Install](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/)".
This problem can also occur if you are using k3s. Then it helps to set a variable:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

You can read more about this problem [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/solved-error-installing-istio-using-istioctl/5254/4).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a cluster running. Try running istioctl version and see what comes up. If it says refused to connect to pods, then you need to start a cluser. For example, if you have minikubes downloaded in your system, use command: minikube start.